# TCP basic understanding issues

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, connection

im trying to run client-server program with my friend. it basic chat.
but even i gave him my ip number it dont manage to connect to start.
we use system.out. println and the client server failed all the after 
waitnig 1 min and print the "didnt manage to connect".
please advice.

public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

```
private JButton btnSend;
private JTextArea txt;
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

**Server SIDE:**

public MyPanel()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(getBtn() , BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(getText() , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        try{
            System.out.println("here");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6600);
            System.out.println("Server's ready");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("after accept");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream() , true);
            out.flush();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String temp;
            while( (temp = in.readLine())!= null)
                out.println(temp);
        }catch(IOException e){}


    }


    public JButton getBtn(){
        btnSend = new JButton("send");
        btnSend.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        return btnSend;
    }

    public JTextArea getText(){
        txt = new JTextArea();
        return txt;
    }

    private class MyAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
```

**Client SIDE**

```
public class Messages extends JPanel{
    private JTextArea txtArea;
    private JButton sendBtn;
    private Socket socket;
    private InetAddress address;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public Messages(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        txtArea = new JTextArea();
        add(txtArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        sendBtn = new JButton("Send");
        add(sendBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addClient();
    }

    public void addClient(){
        try{
            //address = InetAddress.getByName("");
            //System.out.println(address);
            socket = new Socket("**here we type my ip numbeer as string", 6600);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Didn't manage to connect");
        }
        try{
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Buffer problem");
        }
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you doing this across the internet or on a LAN? You may want to check your firewall settings and if it's across the internet, set up NAT and/or open port forwarding (or a DMZ if that suits your needs better).

Comment: were doing it on the same wifi on the internet...

Comment: is the code seemes ok?

Comment: You may be on a Wifi that uses a technique called AP Isolation, which prevents all Wifi clients from direct access with each other in the LAN. To be sure this is not the case, check the configuration of your access point(or router) or try a cabled environment.

Comment: No, it isn't OK. When you get an exception, don't just print out some vague message of your own devising. Print *the message in the exception,* and preferably the stack trace as we'll. That will tell you exactly what the problem was. At the moment all we know is that there was some IIException. Just a guessing name so far. Change your code to do that and paste the result of rerunning it here. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ping the server machine IP & check whether its reachable. If ping works then check the firewall running in the server machine for any rule which blocks the communication.